# HOWTO: remove an un-needed Office Home 2013 "subscription" from MyOffice?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, office365

I've been installing Office on my father-in-law's new laptop. While waiting for the delivery of the copy of Office Professional 2013 that I had ordered I installed the free one month subscription to Office Home 2013. I now have the Office Professional 2013 key and so I have deactivated and uninstalled Office Home 2013 from the laptop. However I cannot see how to remove the "subscription" from his https://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/MyAccount.aspx page. It is important that I remove it because if he visits the page the entire screen is taken up with details of his Office Home 2013 "subscription", stating things like "You haven’t used any installs" and "Press Install to get started" and a giant green "Install" button. My fear is that on seeing this page his (completely natural) reaction will be to click "Install". It is only if he collapses the Office Home 2013 "subscription" or scrolls several screens down on the page that he will see the details for his active Office Professional 2013 subscription. How do I remove the Office Home 2013 "subscription" from his https://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/MyAccount.aspx page?

Comment: I have also asked this on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/howto-remove-an-un-needed-office-home-2013/64856e90-c89d-48f1-8fc3-9f4fd298f21c). I hope cross posting is OK.